# Client web service for english dictionary

Tags: c#, winforms, web-services

I use this service to translate English word:
http://services.aonaware.com/DictService/DictService.asmx?op=Define

I add this link to my windows Form application by click right on References -> Add Service Reference -> and best the URL of service in Address field.

then I write this code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using هجوم_الكسر_الأعمى.ServiceReference1;

namespace هجوم_الكسر_الأعمى
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            //Definition a = new Definition();
            WordDefinition sv = new WordDefinition();
            sv.Word="Go";
            string b= sv.Word;
            textBox1.Text = b; ;

        }
    }
}
```

The problem is that I don't have the result, I have the same world witch I write it "Go"?

Comment: And where is the service call?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're not doing anything here, you're just creating an instance of `WordDefinition` locally that you set to the word you're trying to search for.

You need to invoke the service call, for example..

```
using (var dictionaryService = new ServiceReference1.DictServiceSoapClient("DictServiceSoap"))
{
    var definition = dictionaryService.Define("Programming");
    Console.WriteLine(definition.Definitions.First().WordDefinition);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if I understand you, but if you would like to have result from sv.Word method I think you shloud try to check if there is some method with Result, for example: sv.WordResult and it will add event handler to this.